# MySQL GROUP_CONCAT headache

Tags: sql, mysql, group-concat

For performance,I need to set a limit for the GROUP_CONCAT,

and I need to know if there are rows not included.

How to do it?

**EDIT**

Let me provide a contrived example:

```
create table t(qid integer unsigned,name varchar(30));

insert into t value(1,'test1');    
insert into t value(1,'test2');    
insert into t value(1,'test3');

select group_concat(name separator ',') 
  from t 
 where qid=1;

+----------------------------------+
| group_concat(name separator ',') |
+----------------------------------+
| test1,test2,test3                |
+----------------------------------+
```

But now,I want to group 2 entries at most,and need to know if there is some entry not included in the result:

```
+----------------------------------+
| group_concat(name separator ',') |
+----------------------------------+
| test1,test2                      |
+----------------------------------+
```

And I need to know that there is another entry left(in this case it's "test3")

Comment: I've given a detailed example.Is that clear?

Comment: Thank you for providing an example.  How do you want to know when the list of values exceeds your limit?

Comment: @rexem,there are many cases with this requirement.If the list of values exceeds my limit,should show a "Show All" link.

Answer (score 1):

this should do the trick

```
SELECT 
SUBSTRING_INDEX(group_CONCAT(name) , ',', 2) as list , 
( if(count(*) > 2 , 1 , 0)) as more
 FROM 
   t 
 WHERE 
   qid=1
```

Comment: No,this is indeed a "trick" that does more work to retrieve less,which is not what I want.

Comment: limit in group_concat is not supported at this point , any query based solution will do more work than a simple function call like that one.

Comment: This is probably as close as you can get, and is relatively efficient if you want to get a set data size (e.g. exactly a certain number of values) from the group_concat; but not so much if you want it to behave like a limit.

Answer (score 0):

How are you going to set the limit? And what performance issues will it solve?

You can get the number of rows in a group using `count(*)` and compare it to the limit.

Comment: @Lukáš Lalinský,sorry for my late clarification!